# Handling NHibernate lazy-load exceptions caused by unreachable database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception

I have an app using NHibernate to map the domain and a graphic interface with MVVM pattern. When the network is down the database (not local) is unreachable so I should be able to show a message to the user and close the app without crashing. I can do that at the begining when the app tries to open a session with a try-catch, but it seems very difficult to do that later. It's using lazy-load so  queries to the database happen potentialy everywhere and it's not as simple as using a try-catch. What could I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control what type of exception thrown by NHibernate, you can implement NHibernate.Exceptions.ISQLExceptionConverter and pass that to your Configuration object. 
[Here](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.se/2009/06/improving-ado-exception-management-in.html) is some more information about this interface.

Comment: That's good enough for me. I replaced rethrowing exception with showing a message box and aborting the app execution.